# Print columns from specific line of file?

Tags: string, bash, file-io

I'm looking at files that all have a different version number that starts at column 18 of line 7.

What's the best way with Bash to read (into a $variable) the string on line 7, from column, i.e. "character," 18 to the end of the line? What about to the 5th to last character of the line?

Comment: By "columns" do you mean "characters" or "fields"?

Comment: Characters. Sorry, TextMate calls them columns.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Yes, "characters."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` way:

```
variable=$(sed -n '7s/^.\{17\}//p' file)
```

EDIT (thanks to commenters): If by columns you mean fields (separated with tabs or spaces), the command can be changed to

```
variable=$(sed -n '7s/^\(\s\+\S\+\)\{17\}//p' file)
```

Comment: That's 17/18 *characters*. I wonder of the OP means *fields* when he says "columns".

Comment: @Dennis Edited in case I misunderstood the question.

Comment: `sed -n '7s/^.\{17\}//p' file` works! :) `sed -nr '7s/^(\s+\S+){17}//p' file` doesn't work for me: `sed: illegal option -- r`.

Comment: @MattDiPasquale It can be done without `-r`, just with more slashes (see the update). However, if the first command works, then the second one won't do what you expect it to: it is designed for a file with tab- or space-separated columns of variable width.

Comment: @LevLevitsky what if instead of reading all the way to the end of the line, I wanted to stop at the 5th to last character of the line?

Comment: @MattDiPasquale Reduce the problem to a solved one :) You know how to remove the first 17 chars, now you need to remove the last 5: `s/.\{5\}$//`. To attribute two commands to the 7th line, use the syntax `7{com1;com2}`. Or if you really want to do it in one command, it would be `7s/^.\{17\}\(.*\).\{5\}$/\1/p`.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
var=$(head -n 17 filename | tail -n 1 | cut -f 18-)
```

or

```
var=$(awk 'NR == 17' {delim = ""; for (i = 18; i <= NF; i++) {printf "%s%s", delim, $i; delim = OFS}; printf "\n"}')
```

If you mean "characters" instead of "fields":

```
var=$(head -n 17 filename | tail -n 1 | cut -c 18-)
```

or

```
var=$(awk 'NR == 17' {print substr($0, 18)}')
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of different ways you can go about this, depending on the utilities you want to use. One of your options is to make use of Bash's substring expansion in any of the following ways:

#### sed

```
line=1
string=$(sed -n "${line}p" /etc/passwd)
echo "${string:17}"
```

#### awk

```
line=1
string=$(awk "NR==${line} {print}; {next}" /etc/passwd)
echo "${string:17}"
```

#### coreutils

```
line=1
string=`{ head -n $line | tail -n1; } < /etc/passwd`
echo "${string:17}"
```

Answer (score 0):

If by 'columns' you mean 'fields':

```
a=$( awk 'NR==7{ print $18 }' file )
```

If you really want the 18th byte through the end of line 7, do:

```
a=$( sed -n 7p | cut -b 18- )
```